Flutter doctor error : Windows Version (the doctor check crashed)
I am facing this issue after running flutter doctor command:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3880], locale en-US)
[☠] Windows Version (the doctor check crashed)
    X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
      about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    X ProcessException: Failed to find "powershell" in the search path.
        Command: powershell

screenshot
I have seen my environment variables and there is no path for powershell.
I dont know why the issue is coming a lil help will be greatly appreciated.
ANY IDEA??
